# how to see what domain names are using my website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I made a website for a client and I have to send the entire website so he can migrate it himself

There is a big chance he might start selling the website I made to others

is there any code or something I can use to track if other domains are using the site !؟

I will be having access to the site to make some modifications he asked for, and I will remove the tracking code, I just want to know if my website is being used on other websites

Thanks in advance everybody

Comment: You can use after_setup_theme and send info to email for example ? In addition use create log file somewhere if you need more stuff there :)

Comment: Thanks martin, can you tell me more about these please, or refer me to somewhere to read about,  cuz I am not familiar with those terms

Comment: If you have made a website for a client you should know what is after_setup_theme action and wp_mail() - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references, my mind just got blown lol, I did make the website but not from scratch, I used a theme and a page builder + some CSS for styling, I am not familiar with the backend stuff,  That is why I am searching the web for solutions to protect my content, but still don't know how to figure this out+ Lack of resources is keeping me stuck, anything else can help martin !? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

To send email on theme activation you can use the following snippet. Add in your functions.php

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
    wp_mail( 'snuffybg@gmail.com', 'Theme was activated', 'Theme was activated on following address '.site_url().' .' );
}
```

Keep in mind some servers block emails without proper smtp setup so may not work always but you cant prevent that.